# How to sort an array ob objects on the basis of object keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array in following order

```
[
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 22
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 2,
    "value": 22
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 19
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 3,
    "value": 19
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 4,
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 3.230000000000002
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 5,
    "value": 3.230000000000002
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 109
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 7,
    "value": 109
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 25
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 8,
    "value": 25
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 3,
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 17
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 9,
    "value": 17
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 13
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 10,
    "value": 13
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 12,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 13,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 14,
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 15,
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 4,
    "value": 2
  }
]
```

I need to sort it in following order

```
[
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 3.230000000000002
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 5,
    "value": 3.230000000000002
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 4,
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 19
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 3,
    "value": 19
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 22
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 2,
    "value": 22
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 4,
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 15,
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 14,
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 12,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 13,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 13
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 10,
    "value": 13
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 17
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 9,
    "value": 17
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 3,
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 25
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 8,
    "value": 25
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 109
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 7,
    "value": 109
  }
]
```

So far I have tried below, first sort on base of `source,target and value`, now I don't know how to sort in second step to get desired out. Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

```js
var data = [{
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 22
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 2,
    "value": 22
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 19
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 3,
    "value": 19
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 4,
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 3.230000000000002
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 5,
    "value": 3.230000000000002
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 109
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 7,
    "value": 109
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 25
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 8,
    "value": 25
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 3,
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 17
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 9,
    "value": 17
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 13
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 10,
    "value": 13
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 11,
    "value": 11
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 12,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 13,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 14,
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 15,
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 4,
    "value": 2
  }
];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.source - b.source || a.target - b.target || a.value - b.value;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**UpDate 1**
There is a relationship b/w source and target. Sorted array should be in the following sequence

smallest element named "A" based on source, target, value
source  = smallest source
target = smallest target
value = smallest value

all the elements who's
source = element A target
target =
Value  = element A value
..................
Next smaller element named "B" based on source, target, value
source  = smaller source
target = smaller target
value = smaller value

all the elements who's
source = element B target
target =
Value  = element B value
...................
Next small element named "C" based on source, target, value
source  = small source
target = small target
value = small value

all the elements who's
source = element C target
target =
Value  = element C value

so on and so forth.

Comment: There are a lot of irrelevant properties and a large number of objects there, can you remove some of them, so we can more clearly see the logic you're looking for? Eg 10 items with 3 or 4 properties each is good, but 400 lines of an array literal is a bit much

Comment: What would be the second step? What keys should the resulting array be ordered by?

Comment: It seems you have some logical basis for sorting. It will be better if you can explain that also. Finding logic by ourselves in such a big dataset is cumbersome.

Comment: Your desired result isn't even sorted by the first step, so it's really unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  I have removed the irrelevant properties

Comment: Can you explain what logic you're trying to implement in words? If you want sort in order of lowest value, then lowest target, then lowest source, `{
    "source": 6,
    "target": 12,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 7
  },` in your desired output doesn't seem to match that pattern, since the higher target is coming first there when the value is the same

Comment: @CertainPerformance,@Barmar,@Sunil Chaudhary I have updated the question and tried to explain in words, Hope you will understand

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have updated the question and tried to explain in words, Hope you will understand

Comment: @Barmar  I have updated the question and tried to explain in words, Hope you will understand

Comment: @Sunil Chaudhary I have updated the question and tried to explain in words, Hope you will understand

Comment: No, it's still not clear. What are `A`, `B`, `C`?

Comment: It sounds like what you really need to do is filter the array based on the `A`, `B`, and `C` criteria, then concatenate each of those. You use `sort()` when the criteria is comparing the values of elements with each other.

Comment: @Barmar `A` will be the first element of sorted array(smallest element as I explained based on source,target and value ), then there will be n elements(having source = element A target and Value = element A value). Then there will element `B(bigger than A in value)` then n elements, then C bigger than B so on and so forth

Comment: Why is `{
    "source": 1,
    "target": 5,
    "value": 3.230000000000002
  }` before `{
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "value": 19
  }` in the sorted array? It has a larger `source`.

Comment: Oh, I think I'm getting it. You want to first sort by `source, target, value`. Then you want to group together the elements with the same `source` and `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep the same group by looking at previous `target and following`source``, group them together, sort by value and get a flat array of objects.

```js
var data = [{ source: 0, target: 1, value: 22 }, { source: 1, target: 2, value: 22 }, { source: 0, target: 1, value: 19 }, { source: 1, target: 3, value: 19 }, { source: 0, target: 1, value: 12 }, { source: 1, target: 4, value: 12 }, { source: 0, target: 1, value: 3.230000000000002 }, { source: 1, target: 5, value: 3.230000000000002 }, { source: 0, target: 6, value: 109 }, { source: 6, target: 7, value: 109 }, { source: 0, target: 6, value: 25 }, { source: 6, target: 8, value: 25 }, { source: 0, target: 6, value: 20 }, { source: 6, target: 3, value: 20 }, { source: 0, target: 6, value: 17 }, { source: 6, target: 9, value: 17 }, { source: 0, target: 6, value: 13 }, { source: 6, target: 10, value: 13 }, { source: 0, target: 6, value: 11 }, { source: 6, target: 11, value: 11 }, { source: 0, target: 6, value: 7 }, { source: 6, target: 12, value: 7 }, { source: 0, target: 6, value: 7 }, { source: 6, target: 13, value: 7 }, { source: 0, target: 6, value: 6 }, { source: 6, target: 14, value: 6 }, { source: 0, target: 6, value: 4 }, { source: 6, target: 15, value: 4 }, { source: 0, target: 6, value: 2 }, { source: 6, target: 4, value: 2 }],
    result = data
        .reduce((r, o) => {
            let last = r[r.length - 1];
            if (last && last[last.length - 1].target === o.source) last.push(o);
            else r.push([o]);
            return r;
        }, [])
        .sort(([a], [b]) => a.source - b.source || a.target - b.target || a.value - b.value)
        .flat();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can u please also share EMCA script 5 version as well?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are genius.

Comment: There a small problem, your sorted array has missed an element as compared to my result array. `{
  "source": 0,
  "target": 6,
  "value": 7
}`

Comment: it is here `{
    "source": 6,
    "target": 14,
    "value": 6
  },
  {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 6,
    "value": 7
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 12,
    "value": 7
  },`

Comment: In the above link left side is my result array.

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: There are two elements `{ "source": 0, "target": 6, "value": 7 }` in unsorted array. But sorted array has one.

Comment: In sample data tree is of level2, but it can have more than two levels.

Comment: it looks like, you want all pathes to the parents as well. please see in the first part the resutl please check with your mor leveled data.

Comment: Can you please compare your result to my desired result. They are not same one element is missing from you result.

Comment: please have a look ... ;-)